# Excel Formula - Find if a value appears in a column according to a specific value in the row of a different column

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find the formula that will return a "yes" or "no" in a column according to whether the value of the cells on the same rows of different columns match specific values.  So for example

Column A contains different sample dates.
Column B contains a sample reference P1, P2, N3, N3 against each of the different sample dates.
Column C contains sample results "Yes", "No" or "N/S".

In a second worksheet, I have a summary table.  Column A contains P1, P2, N3 and N4 over four rows.

The formula is needed for Column B - "Yes" against P1 in Column A if any cell in Column C on the first worksheet contains "Yes" against P1 in Column A on the first worksheet or "No" if the cells contain "No" or "N/S".  Hopefully I'm making that test clear?  So for example, if the data table of the first worksheet contained the following:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
14/04/2015  P1          Yes
14/04/2015  P2          No
14/04/2015  N3          No
14/04/2015  N4          No
03/05/2015  P1          N/S
03/05/2015  P2          No
03/05/2015  N3          Yes
03/05/2015  N4          No
16/06/2015  P1          N/S
16/06/2015  P2          No
16/06/2015  N3          N/S
16/06/2015  N4          No
```

The summary table on the second worksheet would return:

```
Column A    Column B
P1          Yes
P2          No
N3          Yes
N4          No
```

To make things slightly more complicated, the formula needs to work by column and not specific cells, because it needs to work as a template for multiple tests and each test might have a different number of dates and/or number of sample references.  I have tried multiple combinations of IF with AND, If with OR and AND and attempted an INDEX in there too, but I just can't find the answer that works with different data sets. I'm sure excel can do it, I'm just running out of ideas with my limited knowledge.

Comment: could you please provide a nice and clear screenshot of your data? and the expected results as well. Provide the link to the screenshot and we will update the question to show the image. Or provide a sample data in the question text.

Comment: Shot of the example data:

Comment: Sorry - the screenshot isn't coming up.  This is my first post and it seems to want me to have "at least 10 reputation" to insert an image into the post?

Comment: add the screenshot link to the question or add it here in the comments, we will update it.

Comment: why don't you copy paste your excel data here, and choose the 'code' to format it?

Comment: please include any formulas that you have tried but have failed.

Answer (score 0):

So you can put the following formula in cell **B2** in `Sheet2`

```
=IF((IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$B:$B=$A2)*(Sheet1!$C:$C="Yes"),0)),"No")="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

**this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.**

And then copy and fill down until **B5**.

In the formula, `Sheet1` refers to the sheet that contains your initial table with three columns.

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried this.  It seems to work, hurrah!  I will need to test it with a few different data sets, but I think that's got it.  This will save hours, if not days, in the future...Thanks!

Comment: @RAR [what should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please click the check mark below the vote count to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it with this ...

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,A2,Sheet1!C:C,"Yes")=0, "No", "Yes")
```

Basically do a `COUNTIF` on 2 ranges:

Range 1: Find all the "`P1`" (or "`P2`", "`N3`", etc.) - `A2` points to your 2nd sheet, Column A.
Range 2: Find all "`Yes`" ...

`COUNTIFS` does an AND on those, so they both have to be true ... 
Check the count, 0 = No .. anything else = Yes.  ;)